# IOS7 pause AVAudioPlayer music in another controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7

How to pause AVAudioPlayer music in another controller
This my code

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer1;
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *music=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioPlayer1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];

    [audioPlayer1 play];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];




    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer1;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if(event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        switch(event.subtype)
        {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                [audioPlayer1 pause];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                [audioPlayer1 pause];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                [audioPlayer1 play];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doe not work. How can I fix or work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audioPlayer1 property in your AppDelegate does not point to your audioPlayer1 in your ViewController. You can do it like this:

AppDelegate.**H**

[image: appdelegate]

ViewController.**M**

[image: viewcontroller]

Edit answer to second question:

If CDVStream is another UIViewController than use the same approach to point the AppDelegate property to your CDVStream property. The thing to understand is that the AppDelegate holds the audioPlayer and you use the properties in your ViewControllers to regulate it's behaviour by using an audioPlayer property that points to it.

So do it like this:

- in your **CDVStream.M** import the AppDelegate `#import "AppDelegate.h"`
- also import the AVFoundation framework `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`
- add the AVAudioPlayerDelegate to interface `@interface CDVStream () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`
- make a AVAudioPlayer property `@property (strong, nonatomic)AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer;`
- in your `viewDidLoad` method set your audioPlayer property to point to the AppDelegate's property.

Not a big fan of separate pieces of info/code so the screen below contains all above:

[image: CDVStream audioPlayer]

Comment: Thank you michael for answer my questions
But i'm mean if AVAudioPlayer has play on CDVStream
and control AVAudioPlayer in background on ViewController

Comment: If CDVStream is an UIViewController then you can not keep the AVAudioPlayer in the background. You either have to create a Singleton (like the AppDelegate is) which stays alive for the entirety of the apps life, or pass the audioPlayer property to the new ViewController before the other one is getting dismissed through prepareForSegue for example.

Comment: Thanks for this @Michael +1